# Write Hive queries to see how many missing values you have in each attribute

Tags: hive

I want write hive query such that it I can see count of null values of each column

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SQL - this will give you total count, null and not null count.

```
SELECT 
count(*) total_cnt,
sum(case when data_col is null then 1 else 0 end) null_cnt,
sum(case when data_col is null then 0 else 1 end) nonnull_cnt
From mytable
```